Pure complex equilibrium point, can I conclude anything about its stability?
In a dynamic system:
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} &= -D_2 \dot{y}^2 - R_2 + F_2 + D_1\dot{x}^2 + R_1 - F_1 \\
\ddot{y} &= -D_3 \dot{z}^2 - R_3 + F_3 + D_2\dot{y}^2 + R_2 - F_2 \\
\ddot{z} &= -D_3 \dot{z}^2 - R_3 + F_3 \\
\end{align}
Where $D_i, R_i \in R^{*}_{+}$. F is the input so it will be 0.
The equilibrium points (P) are:
$
\dot{x} = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{-R_1}{D_1}} \right )\\
\dot{y} = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{-R_2}{D_2}} \right )\\
\dot{z} = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{-R_3}{D_3}} \right )
$
The equilibrium point are pure complex numbers.
I'm not sure if I found the equilibrium points correctly. Can equilibrium points only be found for first-order ODE?
Does it make sense linearize (using Taylor series) around these points?
Can I conclude anything about its dynamic system stability?

By equilibrium point, do you mean an equilibrium point of the dynamical system in $x',y',z'$ ? If so, why isn't it $z'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{F_3-R_3}{D_3}}$ et cetera?

@SassatelliGiulio Sorry, I forgot to mention that F is the input, so it will be 0.

Why mention $F$ at all, then?

@SassatelliGiulio When I linearize the function around the equilibrium point, F appear.

If your system is truly at equilibrium, then the first-order time derivatives should also be zero. It is unclear what you are trying to do here.

I think the following two system show the same property that got you confused and are much simpler than the system you presented. First, let
$$
  \dot{x} = 1,
$$
which is a system without an equilibrium. Second, let
$$
  \dot{y} = y^2+1,
$$
which is a system with no real equilibrium.

I'm not sure if I found the equilibrium points correctly. Can equilibrium points only be found for first-order ODE?

The order of the ODE is not what causes issues, you can find equilibria for all sorts of ODE. But once you have nonlinear systems you are no longer guaranteed to have an equilibrium at zero (as you do in the linear case), and depending on the ODE you could have no equilibria, or have many real and complex equilibria.

Does it make sense linearize (using Taylor series) around these points?

Usually the linearization around an equilibrium relies on the Hartman–Grobman theorem to say something about the behavior of the system close to that particular equilibrium.

Can I conclude anything about its dynamic system stability?

In both systems I presented there are no real equilibria, and for both system we will have that for any initial point $x(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ for a small $t>0$ we will have $x(t)\geq x(0)+t $. Looking at the linearizarion near the complex equilibria tells you nothing about their stability, because your system will evolve over the reals, and will never be "close" to those equilibria.
Now, if we add control to those system:
$$
  \dot{x} = 1 + u, \\
  \dot{y} = y^2+1 + v,
$$
we can select nonzero $u$ and $v$, as an example $u=-1+\tilde{u}$ and $v=-1-\bar{v}+\tilde{v} $, and then have that for $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{v}$ small there will be real equilibria:
$$
  \bar{x} = 0, \\
  \bar{y} = \pm(\bar{v})^{1/2}.
$$
And for these real equilibria the linearization at them might give you something about the local behavior of the system (local stability/instability/etc).
